# How to convert log to CSV format using sed function?

Tags: csv, sed

I have some log content in a file named as `log1.log` which I want converted to a CSV format file named as `output1.csv`. I have given the log file content as below:

```
35 - - [30/Apr/1998:22:00:17 +0000] "GET /images/home_sponsor.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2491
```

I have written a Linux command to perform this task as shown below:

```
sed -E 's/.*\[(.*)\] "(.*)" (.*) (.*)/\1,\2,\3,\4/' log1.log > output2.csv
```

By using the above command, I can only get the output from the date/time till the end into the CSV file, not the beginning '35' value. Also I want the date-time as date and time in separate columns in the CSV file. Currently it is showing the date and time in a single column. Could anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Seems you are looking at a logfile from a webserver. Usually you can reconfigure webservers to deliver different (maybe easier to parse) logfiles.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: is timezone always +0000 or does it change during summertime?

Comment: Is this [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) ? Can the ident and authuser fields ever contain whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `sed` command with `-E` option to enable ERE. This is using regex `^([0-9]{2})([[:space:]]-){2}[[:space:]]\[([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^:]*):([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]\+[0-9]{4}\].*$` which is creating 6 capturing groups and while performing substation using 5 of them to get required output.

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]{2})([[:space:]]-){2}[[:space:]]\[([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^:]*):([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]\+[0-9]{4}\].*$/\1,\3,\4,\5,\6/'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` please try following solution.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
match($0,/^([0-9]{2})(\s-){2}\s\[(\S+)\s\+[0-9]{4}\]\s"GET.*$/,arr1) && split(arr1[3],arr2,"[/:]"){
  print arr1[1],arr2[1],arr2[2],arr2[3],arr2[4],arr2[5],arr2[6]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex and the CSV generator in Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -ne 'puts CSV.generate{|csv|  
    csv<<$_.scan(/^[^\[]+\[([^\]]+)\]\s+"([^"]+)"\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/).flatten
}' file
```

You *can* use a similar pattern with `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/^[^\[]*\[([^]]*)][^"]*"([^"]*)"[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]*)/\1,\2,\3,\4/p' file
```

Either, with your example, prints:

```
30/Apr/1998:22:00:17 +0000,GET /images/home_sponsor.gif HTTP/1.0,200,2491
```

Answer (score 0):

The '35' in the beginning of the line is contained in the first part of your expression `.*\[`, where the .* will consume everything until the first bracket is found.

So you could replace that with something more extensive, plus make this a capture group so you can reference it:

```
(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\[(.*)\] "(.*)" (.*) (.*)
```

This should give you access to the first element, while still checking for the next two columns (which currently only contain a '-'). Also you have two capture groups for date and time separately like so:

```
(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\[([^:]*):([^\]]*)\] "(.*)" (.*) (.*)
```

Plus watch out the end of your expression. I am wondering how that would work out. Several .* behind each other give many options to the engine.

Let's verify this using https://regex101.com:

[image]

From the coloring you can see that date and time were identified by separate capture groups. Also the match information is quite clear on this:

[image]

Just look at groups two and three.

Comment: Hi. I have tried to separate the date and time but it isnt working.

Comment: The date-time is like this '30/Apr/1998:22:00:17 +0000'. I wanted to separate the date and time from this into separate columns.

Comment: Well, it works for me. See my edited response. So what do you get?

Comment: Regarding `[^\]]` - you shouldn't escape `]` when it's the first (or only in this case) character inside a bracket expression as YMMV with what different tools do with that as it's undefined behavior but I'd expect most tools to interpret it as a bracket expression containing a single ```\``` character followed by a literal `]`. Just get rid of the escape and use `[^]]` instead to be portable to all tools.

Comment: Regarding `\[(.*)\]` - you shouldn't escape `]` when you mean it to be literal as it's already literal unless it follows a `[` that starts a bracket expressions (and isn't the first non-`^` char inside that bracket expression) and escaping a literal character is undefined behavior per POSIX.

Comment: Maybe regexp101 is checking PCRE syntax (which may or may not treat ```\``` inside a bracket expression differently from POSIX, idk) rather than BRE or ERE syntax as defined by POSIX and used by `awk`, `sed -E`, and `grep -E`?

Comment: That is not a maybe: rexexp101 is configurable on the left side about which regexp flavor to use. Since nothing else was mentioned in the question I did not bother much and thus my expression works on the default PCRE2. Switching through the different flavors it seems programming languages do not like the unescaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to output valid CSV you need to do more than just copy input strings to output. For example given this input:

```
$ cat file
35 - - [30/Apr/1998:22:00:17 +0000] "GET /images/home_sponsor.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2491
35 - - [30/Apr/1998:22:00:17 +0000] "GET /foo, a "problem", bar/home_sponsor.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2491
```

The output would need to have the double quotes within the strings escaped by doubling them, and any field containing a comma or double quote enclosed in double quotes:

```
35,-,-,30/Apr/1998,22:00:17 +0000,"GET /images/home_sponsor.gif HTTP/1.0",200,2491
35,-,-,30/Apr/1998,22:00:17 +0000,"GET /foo, a ""problem"", bar/home_sponsor.gif HTTP/1.0",200,2491
```

The above is the output of this command, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s/\S` shorthand:

```
awk -v FS='^$' -v OFS=',' '
    match($0,/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+[[]([^]:]+):([^]]+)]\s+(\S+|".*")\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*/,a) {
        for ( i=1; i in a; i++ ) {
            if ( a[i] ~ /[",]/ ) {
                gsub(/^"|"$/,"",a[i])
                gsub(/"/,"\"\"",a[i])
                a[i] = "\"" a[i] "\""
            }
            $i = a[i]
        }
        print
    }
' file
```

If you don't want all of the fields output then just change `print` to `print $1, $4, ...` as you like.